# PHP Session Variables are not passed to next page

Tags: php, session, variables

I have 2 PHP pages in the same folder. I am trying to set a session variable on one page (test.php), then read its value on another (test2.php). However, the session variable gets lost on the second page.

**test.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["test"] = "123hello";
    $hello = $_SESSION["test"];
    echo "out: $hello";

    $sid = session_id();

    echo "<br> sid: $sid";

    ?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$hello = "test";
if(isset($_SESSION["test"]))
{
    $hello = $_SESSION["test"];
}
echo "out: $hello";

$sid = session_id();

echo "<br> sid: $sid";

?>
```

First I visit test.php, which outputs:

> out: 123hello

Then I visit test2.php, which outputs:

> out: test

Which means in test.php, the session variable does keep its value. However, for some reason it gets lost in test2.php.

Comment: test2.php also gives the same o/p i.e out: `123hello` check once again. and also `session_start();` should be the first line remove space between it.

Comment: test2.php won't give the same output, i am aware of my code being correct so im questioning myself what else isn't working? maybe it has to do with the session permissions? i really don't know but for any reason it's not working

Comment: well i tried your code on my machine it gives the same o/p i.e `123hello ` may be you should check if session exist. `if(isset($_SESSION)){
 echo "yes";
}`

Comment: yea when I set the value of the sessionvarible in test2.php it works as long it's test2.php but as soon as I open another page the session variable is unset... as you can see by the output of test.php sessions DO work on one page but not from page to page...